# Run Xcode 5.1.1 project with Xcode6-Beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I just downloaded and installed Xcode6-Beta on my OS-X 10.9.3 I want to run an iOS6-7 project builded on Xcode 5.1.1 with xCode6-Beta but i have many no sense errors:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Thats are only two examples, i have more than 40 erros.
All the errors are on .h files; i know that in Swift there isn't header files but on my project configuration i have disabled Swift files "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code"

What i have to do for run an Xcode 5 project with Xcode 6?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define @class MBProgressHUD before @interface MXNavigationViewController . I don't think this error has anything to do with Xcode 6. I have run a few projects in it and its ok.

Comment: Sorry maybe i was not so clear on my question, those are two different errors. If you run your Xcode5 project with no problems maybe i failed my install...i don't know. Or maybe some wrong project's settings.

Comment: @MartinoBonfiglioli Have you tried doing a Product > Clean before building?

Comment: I too have perfectly running xcode 5 apps which totally fails in xcode 6. None of the frameworks seems to be imported by default. Even as simple as UIColor is shown as an error. Is this normal?